# $f_n\in L^1$ and $f_n \to f$ in a.e and $|f_n|\leq g$ where $g\in L^1$ then $f\in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

**This is not duplicate I had specific question Please Help me**

I want to prove Dominated convergence theorem: I understand the whole proof except for one part.

Why $f_n\in L^1$ and $f_n \to f$ in a.e and $|f_n|\leq g$ where $g\in L^1$ then $f\in L^1$?

I know that $|f|<|f-f_n|+|f_n|<\epsilon+g$ then
$$
\int |f|<\int (\epsilon+g).
$$
And I know that 
$$
\int g<\infty 
$$
However, even if I can choose $\epsilon >0$ as small as needed, I do not control its integral over the space as $\mu(X)=\infty$. Thus how Can I conclude $f\in L^1$?

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Fatou.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @DavidMitra Fatou is not needed. No theorem is needed. Just definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|f_n| \leq g$  and $f_n \to f$ a.e. imply $|f| \leq g$ a.e. Hence $\int |f| \leq \int g<\infty$.

I have just used the fact that if $|a_n| \leq b$ and $a_n \to a$ then $|a| \leq b$.

Comment: Dear sir $f_n\to f$ not g

Comment: @MathLover Sorry, that was  a typo.

Comment: Sir Sorry Sir I had same confusion Still I mentioned in question How |f|<g even if f_n \to f

Comment: Dear Sir Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: That has  nothing to do with measure theory. If $|a_n| \leq b$ and $a_n \to a$ then $|a| \leq b$.

Comment: Ok Sir I understand now Thanks